# How does MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser know when an invitation has timed out?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, multipeer-connectivity

In my MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser delegate, my advertiser:didReceiveInvitationFromPeer:withContext:invitationHandler waits for the user to either accept or decline the session. If the user waits long enough to accept/decline, it's possible for the browsing peer that sent the invitation to have the invitation time out.

I currently have no way of knowing that the invitation timed out on the receiving end, other than inspecting the session after the fact to see if any other peers are in it, but obviously I'd prefer to know that the invitation expired at the moment it expires so I can dismiss my accept/reject screen automatically. Any ideas on how I could do this?

Comment: default timeout for invites are 30 seconds, why not create a nstimer to execute and valid the session.

Comment: I thought about that, but the issue is that the timer on the receiving side won't be in sync with the timer on the sending side... Suppose my timeout is 30 seconds. The sending timer starts when I send the invitation, but it may take 5, 10, 20 seconds for the receiver to get the invitation. At this point, I have no idea how much time is left on the sender's timer, so I can't properly set the receiver's timer to match...

Comment: granted this can not be in sync too (tho the default on iPhone is syncing the time of the phone with the network), you could try sending timestamp in the context data..?

Comment: @jamdaddy25 I totally agree. You should expand this comment to an answer!